# Getting the URL from the address bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an iframe on `mynewwebsite.com` showing content from `mywebsite.com`

```
alert(window.location.hostname);
```

always shows `mywebsite.com`, is there any way I could get the URL from the user's address bar without modifying anything on `mynewwebsite.com`?

I want to check the domain and load stylesheets accordingly.

Comment: Are you calling that from within the iframe?

Comment: @putvande yes, from within the iframe.

Comment: I think `window` object refers to the current window (the iframe's window object) because you're calling it from the iframe. Try `window.parent.location.hostname`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this

```
var url = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? document.referrer: document.location;
```

Comment: Just one thing...it shows the whole URL, how do I check for just the domain name?

Comment: can you substring between the start and the first index of / ?

Comment: I didn't know about `document.referrer`. Thanks, +1.

Comment: This isn't fool-proof, for example if I follow a link within the iframe, the referrer becomes the url of the iframe source. Any workaround? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think `window` object refers to the current window -- the iframe's window object because you're calling it from the iframe.

Try

```
window.parent.location.hostname
```

But since they are two different domain names you will encounter a cross-site-scripting security (aka XSS) limitation. You have to configure your servers to allow XSS between the two domains.

Comment: `Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://mywebsite.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://mynewwebsite.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
alert(window.parent.location.hostname);
alert(window.top.location.hostname);
```

It works in Chrome like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

```
var URL = window.location.href;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
var myIframe = document.getElementById('yourIframeId');

alert(myIframe.contentWindow.location.hostname);
```